# Как перенести данные о выделенной строке в Datagridview на другую форму?

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, datagridview, forms

Есть такой код

```
        int index;
        index = dgBooks.CurrentRow.Index;
```

dgBooks это DataGridView
как мне перенести значение переменной index на другую форму

Answer (score 0):

Когда мы в главной форме запускаем вторую форму

```
form2 f = new form2(index);
f.ShowDialog();
```

в form2 f = new form2(); нужно записать нашу переменную получится

```
form2 f = new form2(index);
```

На второй форме нужно вписать эту переменную

```
public class MyForm
{
 private readonly int _index;


  public MyForm(int index)
  {
      _index = index;
  }
}
```

и вот у нас есть переменная _index , которая равна переменной index с другой формы